# Should I use a comma in this sentence before "and"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Could you please tell me if the punctuation of the following sentence is correct:

> I know I would be an asset to your team and my knowledge and international experience will be a very good foundation for future work at Y-Company Name.

I am very confused regarding the "and" comma rules in this case.

Comment: Because you have two "and"s doing different work (first is joining two sentences into a single one, second is joining two assets), you might consider a comma after the first one, but it is not required.  However, you're better off with the second sentence as an explanation of the first, as follows.  "I know I would be an asset to your team: my knowledge and international experience ...".

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and reply!